# show data in columns using gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I am trying to show data in 2 column.. e.g

```
col       col            

A          E       
B          F       
C          G       
D          H
```

I am able to show single column but I am unable to show 2 columns, when I add the new field in gridview to show the columns it displays the same column. like

```
col       col            

A          A       
B          B       
C          C       
D          D
```

I wanted to show data in continuity. Please suggest me a solution. 
Thanks

```
 <asp:GridView 
       ] ID="GridViewProducts" 
        DataKeyNames="pkProductId,RetailPrice"
        runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="getSelectedRowToCard"            
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        AllowPaging="True"  
        PageSize="4"
        OnPageIndexChanging="OnNewPage"
        BorderWidth="0px"
        BorderColor="White" Width="341px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="ADD To Card"/>                    
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <br />                            
                        Description:
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="SelectProduct" NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx"                                                    
                        runat="server"><%#Eval("Description").ToString()%> 
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                        <br />
                        TypeDescription: <%#Eval("TypeDescription").ToString()%>
                        <br />
                        <span style="color: #FF3300">RetailPrice:$</span>
                        <%#Eval("RetailPrice").ToString()%>
                        <br />
                        Weight: <%#Eval("Weight").ToString()%>
                        <%--<asp:Button ID=btn runat="server" Text="Add to Cart"
                        OnCommand="getSelectedRowToCard"/>--%>
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:HyperLinkField />
                <asp:CommandField SelectText="ADD To Card" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <br />
                        Description:
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="SelectProduct" runat="server"                
                        NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx"><%#Eval("Description").ToString()%>
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                        <br />
                        TypeDescription: <%#Eval("TypeDescription").ToString()%>
                        <br />
                        <span style="color: #FF3300">RetailPrice:$</span>
                        <%#Eval("RetailPrice").ToString()%>
                        <br />
                        Weight: <%#Eval("Weight").ToString()%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:HyperLinkField />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Show us your code pls.

Comment: Downvote : Without seeing your code how can one tell you what's the problem?

Comment: I would suggest you to use Datalist rather than Grid view, you can set your columns easily in datalist.

Comment: I have added the aspx code ...

Comment: I am unable to add the screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using a [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control instead of the GridView.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23559/Working-with-the-DataList-Control) is a quite nice tutorial about how to use it, and [here](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-DataList-RepeatColumns-RepeatDirection-and-RepeatLayout-Properties.aspx) you can find information about it's [`RepeatDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`RepeatLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`RepeatColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties.

For example, by setting `RepeatColumns` to `2`, `RepeatLayout` to `"Table"` and `RepeatDirection` to `"Vertical"` you can achieve the layout you are after:

```
A   E
B   F
C   G 
D   H
```

If you are curious about the performance of the control you can find a nice comparison [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx).